# How to prove $f(n)$ is one by one function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we want to show $A$ has same cardinality of $ B$ we use a function one to one and onto ,to prove $card(A)=card(B)$.

To prove $\mathbb{N}\sim\mathbb{Z}$ we can use $$f(n):\mathbb{N}\mapsto \mathbb{Z}\\f(n)=(-1)^n\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$$ 
so$$1 \mapsto 0\\2\mapsto+1\\3\mapsto -1\\4 \mapsto+2\\5\mapsto -2\\6\mapsto+3\\7\mapsto-3\\\vdots$$ this obvious that $f(n)$ is a Bijection ,but I get stuck how to prove it by definition . 
Sorry if my question is intuitive .

Thanks in advance  for any hint,guide or solution (or any Idea more)

Comment: This function can be better studied if you distinguish $n$ even and odd. You can see that even numbers are mapped to positive integers, while odd numbers are mapped to negative numbers.

Comment: If $(-1)^n[n/2]=(-1)^{n+k}[(n+k)/2]$ for $k>0$ then $[n/2]=(-1)^{k}[(n+k)/2]$. Therefore $k$ is even. Hence $[n/2]=[n/2]+k/2$, from which it follows that $k=0$. Contradiction.

Comment: @user470888:I wish I can vote you for +100 ,because of your Idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially your function is

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
\quad\dfrac n2\qquad \text{if $n$ is even}\\
-\dfrac {n+1}{2}\quad \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

**Injectivity:**

Assume $f(a)=f(b)$. Then we have two cases:

If $f(a),f(b)$ are positive, $\frac{a}{2}=\frac{b}{2} \implies a=b$.

If $f(a),f(b)$ are negative, $-\frac {a+1}{2}=-\frac {b+1}{2}\implies a=b$.

**Surjectivity:**

I'll let you finish this one off. Take some $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $x$ is positive, then ... and if $x$ is negative, then ... .

Answer (score 5):

(Intended as a clarifying hint; I will leave further work to you, although I can supply additional details if you indicate where, precisely, you are stagnating.)

To prove that this is a **bijection**, you need to show two things:

**1.** That $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is **onto**. In other words, for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, you must show that there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $f(k) = n$.

**2.** That $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is **one-to-one**. In other words, for all $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$, it must be the case that $f(a) = f(b)$ implies $a = b$.

To prove **1** and **2** above, it may help to break into various cases, such as even versus odd (as suggested in a comment) and/or positive versus negative.